# Problemas con la función lme() en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

estoy intentando usar la función lme() en R para analizarla el efecto de unos factores determinados en mi variable "Peso seco", pero me sale el mismo error todo el rato. Esto es lo que estoy poniendo:

```
model <- lme(Tritordeum$`Peso seco` ~ Tratamiento + Hongo + Tratamiento*Hongo,
              random=~1|Tritordeum$Línea,
              na.action = na.omit)
```

Y este es el error que me sale todo el tiempo:

```
Error in parse(text = paste("~", paste(names, collapse = "+"))) : 
  <text>:1:19: unexpected symbol
1: ~ Tritordeum+Peso seco
                      ^
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué me pasa esto? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta, es un SO en español

Comment: Hey, this is [es.so], please translate your question, or it will be closed as "off topic > non official language". Thanks

Comment: Ay, no me había dado cuenta, pues la traduzco.

Answer (score 1):

Asumo que Tritordeum es un data.frame. 
Hay un error de pasrseo debido al espacio en blanco en el nombre de la columna  Tritordeum$`Peso seco` . No es conveniente utilizar espacios en blanco en nombres de columnas o de variables. Prueba cambiando el nombre de esa columna a algo que no tenga espacio, por ejemplo Peso.Seco

La fórmula en `lme` parece tener datos del data.frame y datos en vectores aislados, mezclados (en la misma fórmula). Prueba:

`` pesoSeco <- Tritordeum$`Peso seco` ``
`linea <-Tritordeum$Línea`
`model <- lme(pesoSeco ~ Tratamiento + Hongo + Tratamiento*Hongo, random=~1|linea, na.action = na.omit)`

Otra opción es que los datos estén incluidos en un único data frame Tritordeum, con columnas PesoSeco, Tratamiento, Hongo y Linea (nombres sin espacios en blanco) entonces puedes utilizar los nombres de la columna para la fórmula y el parámetro 'data =':

`model <- lme(pesoSeco ~ Tratamiento + Hongo + Tratamiento*Hongo, random=~1|linea, na.action = na.omit, data=Tritordeum)`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!!! He cambiado los nombres de las columnas tal y como has dicho y ha funcionado! Ya no me sale ese error, mil gracias :)

Comment: No hay por que! Saludos

Comment: @MariaSanchezBermudez, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te ha ayudado a resolver el problema. Saludos.